# Вылетает приложение при запуске камеры

Tags: android, kotlin, камера

Вроде бы все делаю по документации, но как когда, иногда запускается камеры иногда просто выходит из приложения и никакой ошибки не выдает

```
   private fun loadCamera() {
        try {
            startActivityForResult(cameraParse.dispatchTakePictureIntent(), REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO)
        } catch (e: ActivityNotFoundException) {
            Log.i("CAMERA","${e.message}")
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.i("CAMERA","${e.message}")
        }
    }


class CameraParse(val context: Context) {

    lateinit var currentPhotoPath: String

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File = File.createTempFile(
            "JPEG_${SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.US).format(Date())}_",
            ".jpg",
            context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
        ).apply {
            currentPhotoPath = absolutePath
        }

    fun dispatchTakePictureIntent(): Intent =
        Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
            takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(context.packageManager)?.also {
                val photoFile: File? = try {
                    createImageFile()
                } catch (ex: IOException) {
                    null
                }
                photoFile?.also {
                    val photoURI: Uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context,
                        "com.io.unknow.fileprovider",
                        it
                    )
                    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)

                }
            }
        }


}

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.io.unknow.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>

<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="images" path="Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Comment: на вкладке logcat при падении будет много красного текста по логике, и ссылка на строку кода, желательно сюда скинуть то что породит лог падения

Comment: Вот именно что ее нет)

Answer (score 0):

В своем проекте я просто убрал строчку из манифеста
У вас нужно убрать это

```
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"android:required="false" />
```